# How do I change the action on a form with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, redirect, laravel-5.3

I use laravel 5.3

My form like this :

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'shop.process','id'=>'my-form']) !!}
    ...
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

If it meets certain conditions, I want to change the action

My condition in javascript like this :

```
if (true) {
    $('#my-form').attr('action', '/shop/detail')
    return true;
}
```

If the condition is met, it success to convert the url into this:

http://myshop.dev/shop/detail

But, the content is not display

Content from that page just appear when I click the url and enter

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What content you want to change ? Are you trying to change the form field by changing action url ? Then it can't be done like that you need to load form content through ajax or just by reloading the page

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the content of the form youll need to load that form with ajax into the form area.

Assuming that /shop/detail is another form.  You should do it like this. Either using .load(), or .ajax()

```
if (true) {
   $('#my-form').attr('action', '/shop/detail');
   $('#my-form').load('/shop/detail');
   return true;
}
```

Or..

```
if (true) {
    $('#my-form').attr('action', '/shop/detail')
    $.ajax({
       url:'/shop/detail',
       success:function(data){
           $('#my-form').html(data);
       } 
    })
   return true;
}
```

However, the two methods above are unlikely to work, because I doubt your /shop/detail is only the inner form.  Its most likely the entire form.  Ie .  So that means you need to fully replace the element.  Not load the data into the old form.

```
if (true) {
    $.ajax({
       url:'/shop/detail',
       success:function(data){
           $('#my-form').replaceWith(data);
           return true;
       } 
    })
}
```